# inserting the php sendmail fuction into a confirm button within a pop up box

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, sendmail

I am trying to use the sendmail function in php threw a pop up box. i have gotten as far as making the sendmail function and the pop up to work separately. but i haven't been able to figure out how to connect the sendmail in the right way. below is the last working git version i have. any help would be wonderful.

```
{
<tr>
<th align="center">Instrument Serial Number:</th>
<td align="left"><input type="text" class="cInstTravText" name="SerialNumber" id="idSerialNumber"/></td>
<button onclick="drop_check()">comfirm</button>
<p id="drop_check"></p>
<script>
function sendEmail() 
{
$to = 'jonsrod1992@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Test email using PHP';
$message = "test";
//$message = 'hello world.\n\n this is a test for functionality\n\n this is the first try\n place instrument serial Number here--> '<$modelNumber>'<-- there.'; 
$headers = 'From: jonr@twobtech.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: jonr@twobtech.com' . phpversion();
                                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-fwebmaster@example.com'); 
}
function drop_check() {
var x;
if (confirm("transfer and send email!") == true) {
x = "transfered and email sent!";
} else {
x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
document.getElementById("drop_check").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</tr>
```

Comment: why is there php between <script> tags?  maybe i need another cup of coffee...

Comment: You can't mix javascript and php constructs.  PHP is server side, JS is client side.

Comment: You need to put the `mail()` call in a server script. You can run it from Javascript using AJAX.

Comment: i left the call for the send mail out because of the fact where ever i tried to place it the function would not work. I also do not have the <script> tag above the php, that was just an drag and drop error on my behalf as to not put the entirety of my code on here.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're attempting isn't going to work.  The php on your page runs first (server side), and then your pop-up is triggered using JavaScript.  This means you'll need to send the response from the pop-up to another php page which then handles the sendmail.  You can do this via POST in a form submission, or better yet, using an AJAX call, like so (this goes between script tags, preferably at the top or bottom of your page, not in the middle of your HTML):

```
 if (confirm("transfer and send email!")) {
     //if needed, get values from one or more HTML inputs like so:
     var stuff = $('#someInputId').val();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendmail.php",
        data: { data: stuff }  //if you don't need to send any data from your HTML elements this can be ommitted
     }).success(function() {
     //optional: let the user know email was sent
     });
 }
```

You would then put your sendmail code in sendmail.php.  If you're sending any data in the AJAX call, you can retrieve it from $_POST.  sendmail.php would look something like:

```
$body = isset($_POST['stuff']) ? $_POST['stuff'] : 'no stuff';
$to = 'jonsrod1992@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Test email using PHP';
$headers = 'From: jonr@twobtech.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: jonr@twobtech.com' . "\r\n" .
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but... it looks like you may be trying to just throw PHP into your javascript. That is not going to work. Also, if this is just weird reformatting of the code, the sendEmail function is not being called.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could also explain how these things should be fixed...

Comment: i left the call for the send mail out because of the fact where ever i tried to place it the function would not work. I also do not have the <script> tag above the php, that was just an drag and drop error on my behalf as to not put the entirety of my code on here.

Comment: I see, the other answer looks to suffice. I think by trying to sidestep some work in asking the question it was made confusing. The PHP code is going to need to live in a web server environment so that it can be called through a PHP at runtime. Then the `dropCheck` is going to need to perform an ajax call to that server endpoint when the confirm comes back true.